# How to create two different CSV files with the same name but one uses a upper case letters and the other uses a lower case letters

Tags: r, csv

I want to create multiple files for columns in a life table. I thought the easiest way to do this would be to save the files using their variable names (ax, Sx, lx, Lx, ...). However, I cannot get R to create two files based on the same name (one in lower case and one in upper case, e.g. lx.csv and Lx.csv).

To demonstrate the problem:

```
# write a csv as normal
write.csv(mtcars, "d.csv")

# next line seems to replace d.csv rather than create a new D.csv file
write.csv(iris, "D.csv")

# get iris when read back in  
d <- read.csv("d.csv")
head(d)
#   X Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Is this behavior normal and is there a way to force the creation of new file with the upper case name?

I am using Windows and R 4.1.0

## Update

Thanks to @tim for the answer. I had to go through the following steps in Powershell (in admin mode)

1. Run `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux`
2. Restart PC
3. Run `cd C:\folder` to get to the location i want to enable case sensitive file names
4. Run `(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory).FullName | ForEach-Object {fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo $_ enable}`

I wanted to enable case sensitive file names for all the sub directories. I think if I just needed for a single folder I could have used `fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo C:\folder enable` for 3 and 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows' NTFS file system is case insensitive. with the april 18 update sensitivity for specific folders was introduced:
[https://www.howtogeek.com/354220/how-to-enable-case-sensitive-folders-on-windows-10/#:~:text=Windows%2010%20now%20offers%20an%20optional%20case-sensitive%20file,see%20%E2%80%9Cfile%E2%80%9D%20and%20%E2%80%9CFile%E2%80%9D%20as%20two%20separate%20files](https://www.howtogeek.com/354220/how-to-enable-case-sensitive-folders-on-windows-10/#:%7E:text=Windows%2010%20now%20offers%20an%20optional%20case-sensitive%20file,see%20%E2%80%9Cfile%E2%80%9D%20and%20%E2%80%9CFile%E2%80%9D%20as%20two%20separate%20files).

Comment: but keep in mindm if you are about to share the file with other windows users, they might not ahve enabled the case sensitivty so it might be beneficial to use a different naming schema

Comment: many thanks. i had to go through a few extra steps... will put them in the question in case anyone finds this page